# SQlite Query in android using cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

My Query is `SELECT DefaultId FROM tblsample where ('567' = DefaultId) || ('567' = Name)`

In the above query

```
table name = tblsample 
Column Names = DefaultId , Name
Input Value  = 567
```

Now i want to check this value is available in which column from the table and return its **DefaultId**. I am able to achieve this in Sqlite, want to know is there still better way to optimize the query and In android using

```
database.query(boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns,String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

which query i must use in android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this snippet:

```
String table = "tblsample";
String selection = "DefaultId =? OR Name=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"567"};
String[] projection = new String[]{"DefaultId","Name"}; // if you want to fetch only these two columns
```

Before your `database.query`:

```
database.query(true, table, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
```

Change the values for **distinct**, **limit**, **orderBy**, **having** and **groupBy** if you need them.

Comment: i accept your answer but why i must give my selectionArgs an Array instad its a single value

Comment: Usually its an array of values then use it as an array , i dont test it with one value and a single String variable.

Comment: whats wrong with my answer @Munchoo ? i cant understand why you didnt accept my answer :/

Comment: i tried accepting both answers but i do not know that we can accept only one. sorry changed nw

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [**SQLiteDatabase documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))  to guide you.

### Table

- `table = "tblsample";`

### Columns

- `columns = new String[]{"DefaultId"};`

### Where

- `selection = "DefaultId =? OR Name=?";`
- `selectionArgs = new String{"567"};`

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql = "SELECT DefaultId FROM tblsample where (DefaultId = 567) OR (Name = 567)";
Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(sql,null);
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
    //value available
} else{
    //not avail
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `||` in SQLite ?