# Why selectionArgs must be an String array?

Tags: android, sqlite

I answered a question in stack overflow and the user that asked the question ask me:
[SQlite Query in android using cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957644/sqlite-query-in-android-using-cursor/28957867#28957867)

> why i must give my selectionArgs an Array instead its a single value ?

I didn't think about this before and its my question too now.
We must use an array when we have only one value for `selectionArgs` in DB query?
(I hope i right my question in right place)

Comment: because when defining a method you can pass arguments as string or string array,when selection args has multiple values then handling string may be difficult but string array can hold a single values if there is only on selectionargs and multiple values if there are more

Comment: Then we could not use a single String value without array ?

Comment: its just a design choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [relevant documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Basically, `String[] selectionArgs` is an array so you can have one or more arguments for your sql WHERE clause. Since these parameters are used in the `database.query()` method, they're actually building a raw sql query string to be run by SQLite. In the `String selection` parameter, you specify all the WHERE clause column names, like this:

`String selection = "DefaultId =? OR Name=?";`

For every `?` in `selection`, a corresponding WHERE value is substituted from your `selectionArgs` array. So, you should have something like this:

`String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"567", "Bob"};`

The `database.query()` method iterates through `selectionArgs` for every `?` it finds in `selection`. So, the array size should match the number of `?` placeholders you're using in `selection`. (If there are more `?` than `selectionArgs` values, then I believe `null`gets substituted instead. I haven't verified this though.)

So basically, since it's possible to have multiple WHERE values substituted into `selection`, that's why `selectionArgs` is an array instead of a simple String.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) my question is about when we have only one `?` and one value for it why we must pass an array for it and not a string only ! I think an String array take more space in memory instead of a string value .  i hope explain it clear :)

Comment: Whoever designed this class must have decided that it's more common to have multiple where args if you're using substitutions. If you don't have multiple values, it might make more sense for you to avoid using `?` altogether and place your values directly into String selection (e.g. `String selection = "DefaultId=567"`. If you do this, just provide an empty array for the values, like this: `String selectionArgs[] = new String[]{}`